# Swing components not displaying

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I've had this problem many times before while using Java swing. I run the program, and nothing at all displays but the window; the moment you resize it even by a pixel, everything appears perfectly. Could anyone please tell me why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: post some code to show us the problem please.

Comment: for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Call setVisible **AFTER** you've finished adding all the components to the frame

Comment: *"please tell me why this is happening?"*  Because you have never been through the tutorial (I suspect) and are always doing it wrong (seems obvious).  Should I enter that as an answer?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Please do so I can upvote it

Comment: @Robin Nahh..  I was undecided as to whether to issue off some blunt truths or vote to close as 'not a real question'.  I am still wavering on the 2nd, but hoping the first (or whatever) can prompt the OP to post actual code we can pull apart.  ..That's more fun.  :)

Comment: +1 to @MadProgrammers comment. Also make sure the UI is created on `Event Dispatch Thread` via `SwingUtilities.invokeLaterXXX`. and +1 to everyone elses comments too :P. Voted to close unless a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) appears.

Answer (score 3):

Always start with [`invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), use a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), [`pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) the frame and make `setVisible()` *last*.

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(...);
        panel.add(...);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(panel));
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following code will appear at end of GUI code.

`frame.setSize(500,500); // size of the frame`

frame.setVisible(true); // make frame window visible

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to call `setSize`, `pack` is a preferred  method for sizing frames (`setSize` is useful in some minor instances ;))