# Why does secondary frames built using Net-beans GUI Builder not open to size built when made visible?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, look-and-feel

When Secondary Frames are added to a package and the frame is called using `frame.setVisible(true);` the frame shows but when it shows it is not open to the size it is built to but rather to the minimum size the frame can go and the user has to resize it, why is this?

Example image:

[image]

[Here's a link to an SSCCE](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwHlscWPK9UPVXplYjdFVEp1bTA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem would make it easier to help.

Comment: Post the SSCCE in the forum not on another website.

Comment: @camickr as code in my answer??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to `pack()` your frame and *then* call `setVisible()`.

Comment: @Catalina_Island This worked thanks I'll wait a bit to see for a better answer, although I don't see that happening ,since I cannot upVote at this point

Comment: @Ayvadia: Glad to help; here's a little [outline](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13252288/261156) I follow.